# C# calculate function min per given range

Tags: c#, arrays, graph-theory

I need to find the minimum from a given range without running O(n).

The array might be a some diagonal line or a hyperbole. here are three sample arrays:

```
var arrDiag1 = new double[10] { 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5 };
var arrDiag2 = new double[10] { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 };
var arrHyperbole = new double[10] { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
```

I tried building some sort of calculation from the line in the desert exercise but it came out no good.
Anyone has a better idea?

Thanks for the help

**update**

With dasblinkenlight help I managed to get to this method:

```
    private double BinarySearchMin(double[] arr, int left, int leftMiddle, int rightMiddle, int right)
    {
        if (left == right)
            return arr[left];

        if (arr[leftMiddle] < arr[rightMiddle])
        {
            right = rightMiddle;
            leftMiddle = ((right - left) / 3);
            rightMiddle = ((right - left) / 3 * 2);
            return BinarySearchMin(arr, left, leftMiddle, rightMiddle, right);
        }
        if (arr[leftMiddle] > arr[rightMiddle])
        {
            left = leftMiddle;
            leftMiddle = ((right - left) / 3) + left;
            rightMiddle = ((right - left) / 3 * 2) + left;
            return BinarySearchMin(arr, left, leftMiddle, rightMiddle, right);
        }
        if (arr[leftMiddle] == arr[rightMiddle])
        {
            left = leftMiddle;
            right = rightMiddle;
            leftMiddle = ((right - left) / 3) + left;
            rightMiddle = ((right - left) / 3 * 2) + left;
            return BinarySearchMin(arr, left, leftMiddle, rightMiddle, right);
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

In the first array it works but not in the second and third arrays.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Obviously this is easy for a straight line - if the first two values are increasing then the min is the first value in the array else the min is the last value in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the function has only one minimum, use [*Ternary Search*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search):

> ternary search algorithm is a technique for finding the minimum or maximum of a *unimodal* function.

The idea is to split the range in three equal segments, probe at the two search points and then "pull in" the one which does *not* contain the minimum. Assuming search points `i1` on the left side of the interval and and `i2` on the right:

- If f[i1] < f[i2], then the minimum is between 0 and i2; pull in from right
- If f[i1] > f[i2], then the minimum is between i1 and N; pull in from left
- If f[i1] == f[i2], then the minimum is between i1 and i2; pull in from both sides.

The running time of the algorithm is O(log N).

Answer (score 1):

I usually hate answering to homework questions, but I somewhat like this one.

First of all, think of the two "diagonal" cases as nothing special, just a different view on the hyperbole where the minimum happens to be on the edge.

Then, try something like binary search to find the minimum. Have a peek at the two middle elements, look at their relation and decide on which side the minimum will be. Repeat until only one element is left.